# Toggling a Binding<Bool> with a SwiftUI button action

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a simple labeled checkbox in SwiftUI that toggles an `isChecked` when the button is pressed. It's very similar to the example in Apple's [Binding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) documentation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LabeledCheckbox: View {
    var labelText: String
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool

    var checkBox: Image {
        Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isChecked.toggle()
        }) {
            HStack {
                checkBox
                Text(labelText)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LabeledCheckbox_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LabeledCheckbox(labelText: "Checkbox", isChecked: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I interact with this button in "Live Preview" mode, the button action doesn't seem to actually toggle `isChecked`. You can view that [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axyVo.jpg). I put a `print(isChecked ? "checked" : "unchecked")` debug statement in the `action` closure and observed in the console output the that `isChecked` was never being toggled.

I've also attempted to get `LabeledCheckbox`to be toggable by passing in a state variable in `LabeledCheckbox_Previews`. The button is still not toggable.

```swift
struct LabeledCheckbox_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var isChecked = false

    static var previews: some View {
        LabeledCheckbox(labelText: "Checkbox", isChecked: $isChecked)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `isChecked` is a `.constant(false)`, so can't be changed.

Comment: Previously, I've also created a static state variable for `isChecked` and and in `LabeledCheckbox_Previews` and pass it into the view, ala `@State private static var isChecked = false`. That didn't work either.

Comment: The following [binding in SwiftUI Live Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247626/12299030) can be helpful.

Comment: You define type properties with the static keyword. don't use static for property wrapped values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide mutable state, not a constant value. For example like this.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LabeledCheckbox: View {
  var labelText: String
  @Binding var isChecked: Bool

  var checkBox: Image {
    Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
  }

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.isChecked.toggle()
    }) {
      HStack {
        checkBox
        Text(labelText)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var isChecked = false

  var body: some View {
    LabeledCheckbox(labelText: "Checkbox", isChecked: $isChecked)
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```