# SwiftUI preview page, bindable URL?

Tags: xcode, model, binding, swiftui, preview

On my `AdminView_Previews`, I'm trying to display my `AdminView`, and it is required from the view to pass a Bindable object called `userInfo` of type `UserModel`.

`UserModel` has a var called `immagine` from a `URL?`

Here my preview:

```swift
struct AdminView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            NavigationView{
            AdminView(dm: DataManager(), userInfo: bindModelUserInfo())
            }
            
            NavigationView{
            AdminView(dm: DataManager(), userInfo: bindModelUserInfo())
            }
            .previewDisplayName("Test")
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        }
    }
}
```

My `bindingModelUserInfo()`:

```swift
func bindModelUserInfo() -> Binding<UserModel?> {
    
    var variabile : UserModel = UserModel(username: "dm1886", email: "dsadsa@gmail.com", userID: "test", adminLevel: "user", immagine: nil )
    
    let boolVariableBinding : Binding<UserModel?> = Binding(get: { variabile },
                                                            set: { variabile = $0! })
    return boolVariableBinding
}
```

If I pass nil to `immagine` the preview fail to load.

Any idea how to solve this issue? How can I pass an `URL` `immagine` to the preview?

On the simulator app everything works fine.

Comment: See my answer in [Mutable Binding in SwiftUI Live Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247626/12299030), it should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a @State variable that will be fed into the userInfo like this.

```
struct AdminView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    @State var mockUserInfo: UserModel = UserModel(username: "dm1886", 
                                                   email: "dsadsa@gmail.com", 
                                                   userID: "test", 
                                                   adminLevel: "user", 
                                                   immagine: nil)

    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            NavigationView{
            AdminView(dm: DataManager(), userInfo: $mockUserInfo)
            }
            
            NavigationView{
            AdminView(dm: DataManager(), userInfo: $mockUserInfo)
            }
            .previewDisplayName("Test")
            .background(Color(.systemBackground))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        }
    }
}
```

Can you share the code of your `AdminView` as well? The variable `immagine` might not be working because you need to handle the case for the `URL?` inside the `AdminView`. I don't know what's inside your `AdminView`, but handling the path for when `immagine` is nil to return an `EmptyView` could to the trick.